# How to change language in IBM Watson speech to text using R?

Tags: r, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm transcribing various mp3 files in Spanish. I'd like to use IBM Watson's speech to text API using R and am following the instructions in this tutorial (http://rpubs.com/Cartwheel/stt). I'm able to successfully transcribe a test mp3 file with English audio using this code, but I haven't figured out a way to modify it to listen for Spanish audio (the default language is American English).

This is the main function from the tutorial for transcribing mp3s. As it is, it successfully transcribes English audio. In this function, url, username, and password are defined previously.

```
watson.speech_to_text.recognize <- function(audio_file)
{ return(POST(url=paste(url,"/v1/recognize",sep=""),
              authenticate(username,password),
              add_headers("Content-Type"="audio/mp3"),
              body = (file = upload_file(audio_file))  
))}
```

I've tried changing the url ending to something like the following, but have had no success.

```
"{url}/v1/recognize?model=ex-MX_BroadbandModel"
```

Comment: Is your question asking: "can i determine if the language is spanish" OR "I want to translate FROM spanish"?

Comment: Thanks, I want to transcribe Spanish audio. IBM Watson is able to recognize various languages and dialects, but it has to be told what language model to use for transcribing and that's what I'm trying to figure out.